# withdrawn comments

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "withdrawn comments" mean "comments that are shy and quiet"?

> New video, **withdrawn comments**: 6 impeachment trial takeaways
> Source: USAToday  [New video, withdrawn comments: 6 takeaways from Day 2 of Trump's impeachment trial](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2021/02/10/top-takeaways-day-2-donald-trump-impeachment-trial/4459682001/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, 'withdraw a comment' means '[retract](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/retract) a comment'. In other words the comments were taken back or removed from consideration.

Context:

> As Cicilline described the call [Trump to Sen. Mike Lee], Lee shook his head and scribbled on a sheet of paper, “This is not what happened,” which he handed to Trump attorney David Schoen.

> "I'm the only witness," Lee said. And as the only witness on the call, he said he "never made those statements."

> Rep. Jamie Raskin, D-Md., said prosecutors were happy to withdraw the comments that were quoted from the news report.

The alleged comments will not be taken into consideration in the trial.